# Multicolumn query result with 3 references to the same field

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql query joining two columns with one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295323/sql-query-joining-two-columns-with-one)

So I'm having some trouble getting a query right in MySQL.

Here's the table I'm using right now

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qualifications`;
CREATE TABLE `qualifications`(
    `activity` int NOT NULL,
    `group` int NOT NULL,
`tournament` int NOT NULL,
`judge_1` int NOT NULL,
`grade_1` int NOT NULL,
`judge_2` int NOT NULL,
`grade_2` int NOT NULL,
`judge_3` int NOT NULL,
`grade_3` int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`activity`,`group`),
FOREIGN KEY(`activity`) REFERENCES `activities`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`group`) REFERENCES `groups`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`judge_1`) REFERENCES `judges`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`judge_2`) REFERENCES `judges`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`judge_3`) REFERENCES `judges`(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`tournament`) REFERENCES `tournaments`(`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I want is to get the Activity name, group name, tournament name, and all 3 judges names and the grades. Here's the query I have so far:

```
select a.name as Game, t.name as Tornament, g.name as "Group", j.name as Judge1, j.name as Judge2, (q.grade_1+q.grade_2+q.grade_3) as Grades from activities a, groups g, judges j, tournaments t, qualifications c where
a.id = q.activity and t.id = q.tournament and g.id = q.group and g.id = 2;
```

Of course, this works fine except for the judge names... How could I get the 3 judge names in a single result?

Thank you all in advance, and sorry if I couldn't explain myself very well.

Answer (score 0):

Join with `Judges` table to get the names assuming the name is there.

```
    select a.name as Game, t.name as Tornament, g.name as "Group",
          j1.name as Judge1, 
          j2.name as Judge2,
          j3.name as Judge3,
          (q.grade_1+q.grade_2+q.grade_3) as Grades 
    from activities a JOIN judges j1
         ON a.judge_1 = j1.id
         JOIN judges j2
         ON a.judge_2 = j2.id
         JOIN judges j3
         ON a.judge_3 = j3.id
         JOIN qualifications q 
         ON a.id = q.activity 
         JOIN tournaments t
         ON t.id = q.tournament 
         JOIN groups g
         ON g.id = q.group 
     WHERE g.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [@Yogendra Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303327) and if you can tolerate the names being concatenated into a delimited string (you could use as a delimiter something like [U+001e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e/)), you can make only a single pass of the `judges` table by grouping the results with [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation of the `judges.name` column:

```
SELECT   a.name                              AS Game,
         t.name                              AS Tournament,
         g.name                              AS Group,
         GROUP_CONCAT(j.name SEPARATOR 0x1e) AS Judges,
         q.grade_1 + q.grade_2 + q.grade_3   AS Grades 
FROM     activities     a
    JOIN judges         j ON j.id IN (a.judge_1, a.judge_2, a.judge_3)
    JOIN qualifications q ON a.id = q.activity 
    JOIN tournaments    t ON t.id = q.tournament 
    JOIN groups         g ON g.id = q.group 
WHERE    g.id = 2
GROUP BY a.id, t.id
```